# Sorting Array using MPI in C

Tags: openmpi

I want to sort an array with 20 different values using MPI library . the idea is the process 0 will chop the array into 2 equal pieces and send them to process 1 and 2 , after that those two processes will do same thing , but this time they have to spawn 2 workers for each , and the workers have to deal with the sorting, any suggestions ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as how to ask a question

Comment: any suggestions about what?